# How can do bulk operation on workflow states in drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, workflow, view, drupal-views

How can do bulk operation on workflow states in drupal 6?
This photo is Views Bulk Operations snapshot and I install workflow and Views Bulk Operations but these actions is not appear in the drop down list
Take a look at http://drupal.org/node/325506

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 6: In the view that you want to be able to allow Bulk changes of workflow states: Edit > Basic Settings > Style: Bulk Operations > Scroll down to "Selected Operations" and choose "Change workflow state of...(whatever you want)" > Save.

In Drupal 7 (not that you asked, but others will probably like to know): 
Edit > Fields > Add a "Bulk Operations: Content" field. The settings for that field has options to bulk change workflow states.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you probably need [Trigger Unlock](http://drupal.org/project/triggerunlock) to show all the actions you expect to see via workflow, but I can't 100% verify.